# Rsync ignores changed file

Tags: rsync

Using this

```
rsync -v * --exclude /node_modules root@xx.xxx.xxx:/var/www/html
```

I don't seem to upload files in subfolders. If I add the recursive flag it tried to upload everything.

How can I check for any changed file even in a subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

rsync is based on the date and size to define if a file have been changed or not.

the '-a / --archive' option could be a good option to keep all the informations about the file (permissions, date etc)

you can use the -c / --checksum option to ask rsync to be based on the checksum of the file to define if it should be transfered.